# Random image from directory with no repeats?

Tags: php, session, cookies, random, session-cookies

I am successfully able to get random images from my 'uploads' directory with my code but the issue is that it has multiple images repeat. I will reload the page and the same image will show 2 - 15 times without changing. I thought about setting a cookie for the previous image but the execution of how to do this is frying my brain. I'll post what I have here, any help would be great.

```
$files = glob($dir . '/*.*');
$file = array_rand($files);
$filename = $files[$file];
$search = array_search($_COOKIE['prev'], $files);

if ($_COOKIE['prev'] == $filename) {
    unset($files[$search]);
    $filename = $files[$file];
    setcookie('prev', $filename);
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing that shuffle($files) then iterate through $files, wouldn't do it.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to slicks answer, but a little more simple on the session front:

Instead of using `array_rand` to randomise the array, you can use a custom process that reorders based on just a `rand`:

```
$files = array_values(glob($dir . '/*.*'));
$randomFiles = array();
while(count($files) > 0) {
    $randomIndex = rand(0, count($files) - 1);
    $randomFiles[] = $files[$randomIndex];
    unset($files[$randomIndex]);
    $files = array_values($files);
}
```

This is useful because you can seed the rand function, meaning it will always generate the same random numbers. Just add (before you randomise the array):

```
if($_COOKIE['key']) {
     $microtime = $_COOKIE['key'];
else {
     $microtime = microtime();
     setcookie('key', $microtime);
}

srand($microtime);
```

This does means that someone can manipulate the order of the images by manipulating the cookie, but if you're okay with that this this should work.

Comment: The loop just returns `undefined offset: 0` forever

Comment: You're right, I should have tested it. It works now I have updated my answer. Ideone: http://ideone.com/L0hDEF

Comment: What would I use to output the image?

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have no repeats per request? Use session. Best way to avoid repetitions is to have two arrays (buckets). First one will contains all available elements that your will pick from. The second array will be empty for now.

Then start picking items from first array and **move** them from 1st array to the second. (Remove and `array_push` to the second). Do this in a loop. On the next iteration first array won't have the element you picked already so you will avoid duplicates.

In general. Move items from a bucket to a bucket and you're done. Additionally you can store your results in session instead of cookies? Server side storage is better for that kind of things.

Comment: I wanted to use sessions but for some reason they're not working with MAMP.

Comment: Also, to what variables would I apply the bucket technique to?

Comment: Just create two arrays `$array1 = []; $array2 = [];` and mess with them. Focus on that as on your first problem. Then you can think about sessions or cookies. Another problem - sessions don't work on MAMP? I'm sure they do but you're doing something wrong. `/var/log/apache2` and study lectures.

Comment: I add session_start(), then declare a session with `$_SESSION['name'] = "value";`